# Cardinality of the set of orbits

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a (possibly infinite) group and $H \unlhd G$. The normality of $H$ in $G$ naturally introduces the $H$-valued map $(g,h) \mapsto g^{-1}hg$, which turns out to be a $G$-action on $H$. Given $h \in H$, the orbit by $h$ is the set $O_h:=\lbrace g^{-1}hg \mid g \in G\rbrace \subseteq H$. The set $O:=\lbrace O_h \mid h \in H\rbrace$ is a partition of $H$.

Can we state anything on the cardinality of $O$?

Comment: Not without more assumptions. It could be anything between $2$ and $|H|$.

Comment: Does the case $G=\operatorname{Aut}(G')$ and $H=\operatorname{Inn}(G')$ bring something more?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Neither of your two comments is correct.

Comment: I see that $G$ is "sliced" into $P:=\lbrace Hg \mid g \in G \rbrace$ and $H$ into $O:=\lbrace O_h\mid h \in H\rbrace$. A related question it came to my mind is: is there any relevant map we can build up between $P$ and $O$? Anyway, I'll rigorously go through orbit-stabilizer theorem as hinted by @Derek Holt.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the OST (phrased upon my original post) states that there's a bijection between $O_h$ and set of the right cosets of $C_G(h)$ in $G$. Could it be the case that -"likewise"- a bijection exists between $O$ and $G/H$?

Comment: No, why would think that there might be a bijection between $O$ and $G/H$? You could have $G/H$ infinite and $|O|=2$. Roughly speaking, as $G/H$ gets larger, you would expect $O$ to get smaller.

Comment: Right, if only for the fact that -as you said in your first comment- $|O|$ can't exceed $|H|$... I was (wrongly) trying to find a way to "evaluate" somehow $|O|$.